# Vue.js How to set the block width in percent, having a percent variable?

Tags: vue.js

I tried to represent this as a string variable and set the style to width, but nothing.

```
   data(){
            return{
                statusNew: this.status,
                progress: this.initial,
            }
        },

v-bind:stylestyle="{ 'width' : '${progress}%', }"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do as below:

```html
<div :style="{width: progress+'%'}"></div>
```

Here a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zecka/n8shdx13/